# Unable to sign in to Azure Account on VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to sign in to Azure in Visual Studio Code and keep getting:

> "You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection".

My network connection is fine and I've checked in different networks so its not a proxy issue (as suggested in other questions about this topic). I also tried reinstalling all the Azure extensions and deleting cache but it didn't work. I was able to sign in flawlessly about a month ago, both at work and at home, but we migrated our company tenant from GoDaddy to Microsoft and that's the problems started. I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem, because it's delaying my work developing some Azure functions for a client.

Edit:

I get the following message in the VSCode logs for the Azure Account extension every 10 seconds:

> Attempting to reach URL "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"...
> certificate has expired

So, is there a way to look into which certificate is expired for the Azure Account extension? That might be causing the offline problem.

Answer (score 1):

> “You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection”.

You have to check in 2 ways for the above error.

1. Disable & Enable the All Extensions in VS Code and then by logging to Microsoft Azure Account.
   [image]
   OR
   Uninstall & Re-install the Azure Extension only in VS Code and then by logging to Microsoft Azure Account from the VS Code IDE.
   [image]

> Attempting to reach URL “https://login.microsoftonline.com/”…
> certificate has expired

2. Check the alternative solution given in this GitHub [Issue733](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/733#issuecomment-1468239088)-Comment for both of the above errors by the user @*TimMarshaU*.

Comment: Thank you very much! What finally solved it was setting "http.systemCertificates": false in settings.json as the GitHub issue described.

Answer (score 1):

A great debugging tool is using [Network Proxy Test extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrmarti.network-proxy-test), and running extension command "Test Connection" with the URL. It will show the cert error, and print the cert chain (i.e. is there a self-signed cert that's not the root CA??)

I was seeing "certificate has expired" error even though I wasn't seeing anything expired in the cert chain... (not sure what the root problem was here(?))

```
Sending GET request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token...
Received error: certificate has expired (CERT_HAS_EXPIRED)

Retrying while ignoring certificate issues to collect information on the certificate chain.

Sending GET request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token (allowing unauthorized)...
Received response:
- Status: 200 OK
Certificate chain:
- Subject: stamp2.login.microsoftonline.com (Microsoft Corporation)
  Subject alt: DNS:stamp2.login.microsoftonline.com, DNS:login.microsoftonline-int.com, DNS:login.microsoftonline-p.com, DNS:login.microsoftonline.com, DNS:login2.microsoftonline-int.com, DNS:login2.microsoftonline.com, DNS:loginex.microsoftonline-int.com, DNS:loginex.microsoftonline.com, DNS:stamp2.login.microsoftonline-int.com
  Validity: Aug 21 00:00:00 2023 GMT - Aug 21 23:59:59 2024 GMT
  Fingerprint: 3C:30:C8:1E:47:02:55:51:62:EA:28:DF:48:F9:13:58:55:E0:95:AD
- Subject: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA (DigiCert Inc)
  Validity: Sep 23 00:00:00 2020 GMT - Sep 22 23:59:59 2030 GMT
  Fingerprint: 62:6D:44:E7:04:D1:CE:AB:E3:BF:0D:53:39:74:64:AC:80:80:14:2C
- Subject: DigiCert Global Root CA (DigiCert Inc)
  Validity: Nov 10 00:00:00 2006 GMT - Nov 10 00:00:00 2031 GMT
  Fingerprint: A8:98:5D:3A:65:E5:E5:C4:B2:D7:D6:6D:40:C6:DD:2F:B1:9C:54:36
  Self-signed
Local root certificates:
- Subject: C=US O=DigiCert Inc OU=www.digicert.com CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
  Validity: Nov 10 00:00:00 2006 GMT - Nov 10 00:00:00 2031 GMT
  Fingerprint: A8:98:5D:3A:65:E5:E5:C4:B2:D7:D6:6D:40:C6:DD:2F:B1:9C:54:36
  Issuer: C=US O=DigiCert Inc OU=www.digicert.com CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
```

---

In my case, what seems to have **fixed** the problem is to run [vscode in an ***insecure*** mode:](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_ssl-certificates)

```
code --ignore-certificate-errors .
```

then signing in with the Microsoft auth flow, then quitting any `code` process to get back to secure mode.

Now Test Connection shows the `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` error has gone away for `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` (but still correctly rejects a broken site e.g. `https://expired.badssl.com/`)

Comment: This actually helped a lot, changing "http.systemCertificates" to false in settings.json doesn't work anymore for me, so checking this I was able to find the expired certificate that gave the error and delete it. Turns out it was a expired intermediate certificate that wasn't ignored by VS Code. After deleting and restarting VS Code, everything works like a charm.